# Where does strange MIME types come from?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mime-types, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I have a web service for uploading files written in C#.
Front-end application is written in Javascript / HTML5 (using https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

Recently, I was reviewing server logs and found some strange MIME types for PDF files that where sent by client browser, for example:

```
application/unknown
application/force-download
application/force-download/n
application/force-download\n
[application/pdf]
```

Some of them are causing .NET framework throwing exception:

```
MultipartMemoryStreamProvider streamProvider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider); 

"Message Error parsing MIME multipart body part header byte 156 of data segment System.Byte[]."
```

I don't have a clue what to do with that.

Comment: Do you know which "client browser"? Did it send a user agent?

Comment: I don't think it's the web developer's job to code for broken user agents...

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the Content-Type in the request.

```
Content-Disposition:  
form-data;  
name="imagefile";  
filename="C:\Users\Pictures\sid.png"  
Content-Type:
```

(notice the blank Content-Type,  it should be Content-Type: image/png )

```
// within WebAPI you can use code below to log the request body
string requestBody = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```